# How to remove 2 contracts

Tags: contract-deployment

I have 2 contracts to be removed

0xc4ba2bbfc1d35d4a6dc37d7764081a1880e5a281 unable to verify source for some reason.
0xf3db7f7f6419bf537fd24eb530b6eace38850c0c contains 0 tokens.

How do i do this?

Regards,

William

Comment: There's no way to "remove" a smart contract. The closest you can do is call `selfdestruct` somewhere in your code. If your contracts don't have code to do that, then there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 5):

You are violating one of the basic concepts of blockchain.

You can't remove anything!

If the contract has a method in place for disabling its functionality that's fine.

However, it will always remain on the blockchain.